# Adding a child node to specific node in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, treeview, nodes, tree-nodes

I have a treeview on my form and in that treeview there are screen resolutions categorized to their type **(categories: 16:9, 16:10, 4:3 etc...)** and there are one last node which is labelled "**Custom**".

I would like to enable users to add their own resolutions by typing numbers in textboxes and clicking a button.

I have successfully written the code to add nodes but everytime i add a custom resolution, it creates a new root node called "**Custom**". How can I make them go under one "Custom" node?

Here's my code:

```
Form1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Custom").Nodes.Add(TextBox1.Text + "x" + TextBox2.Text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove first `.Add` word in your code:

```
Form1.TreeView1.Nodes("Custom").Nodes.Add(TextBox1.Text + "x" + TextBox2.Text)
```

or make a more safely code

```
Dim customnode as TreeNode = Form1.TreeView1.Nodes("Custom")
If customnode IsNot Nothing Then
    customnode.Nodes.Add(TextBox1.Text + "x" + TextBox2.Text)
End If
```

Comment: Apparently the the name of that node wasn't "Custom" but "Node22". So when I renamed "Custom" in your code to "Node22", it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Form1.TreeView1.Nodes.Find("Custom", True).First.Nodes.Add(TextBox1.Text + ":" + TextBox2.Text)

The Find is used to recursively search for the Node with the key "Custom".